# inserting headline in matlab exporting file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix (input) and want to export it as a text file (output), therefore, I am using the following code in matlab:

```
save('out.txt', 'input', '-ASCII');
```

My question is that how I can insert for example 3 lines (as follow) for its header? I don't want to open the output.txt file in another program, because the size of the output.txt is very large and non of the available softwar can open it. Therefore, I want to do this directly in matlab.

```
These data set are...
It is created by
2013
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot do it using only `save` function. For a quick, I can see two options that might be useful.

**First**. Create a file with the header and then use `save` with `-append` options:

```
input = rand(5);
header = ['These data set are It is created by 2013'];

fileID = fopen('out.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n', header);
fclose(fileID);

save('out.txt', 'input', '-ASCII', '-append');
```

**Second**. Instead of using save, manually use `fprintf` to write everything:

```
input = rand(5);
header = ['These data set are It is created by 2013'];

fileID = fopen('out.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n', header);
fprintf(fileID,[repmat('%f ', [1, size(input, 2)]),'\n'], input);
fclose(fileID);
```

If u want multi-line header, u can do as follows:

```
header = ['These data set are ...\nIt is created by\n2013'];


fileID = fopen('out.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID, [header, '\n']);
fprintf(fileID,[repmat('%f ', [1, size(input, 2)]),'\n'], input);
fclose(fileID);
```